# C# Constructing a JWT token manually not working

Tags: c#, token, jwt

I'm trying to construct a JWT token manually by building the three components and then combining them. According to this: https://jwt.io/ there are three parts to this token; a JWT header, a payload and a signature. The follwoing code seems to successfully generate the first two. but the signature is not correct :

```
public async Task<string> GetJWTToken(string user)
{

    var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    //constructing part 1: header.Encode()
    JwtHeader jwtHeader = new JwtHeader();
    jwtHeader.Add("alg", JwtAlgorithms.HMAC_SHA512);
    var partOne = jwtHeader.Base64UrlEncode();

    //constructing part 2: payload.Encode  
    JwtPayload payload = new JwtPayload();
    payload.Add("sub", user);
    payload.Add("nbf",ConvertToUnixTimestamp(now.AddMinutes(-10)));
    var partTwo = payload.Base64UrlEncode();

    //constructing part 3: HS512(part1 + "." + part2, key)
    var tobeHashed = partOne + "." + partTwo;
    var sha = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigurationHelper.AppSettings("JWTOfferKey")));
    var hashedByteArray = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tobeHashed));
    StringBuilder partThree = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (var hashedByte in hashedByteArray)
    {
        partThree.Append(hashedByte.ToString("X2"));
    }

    //token = part1 + "." + part2 + "." + part3
    var tokenString = partOne + "." + partTwo + "." + Base64Encode(partThree.ToString());

    return tokenString;
}

public static double ConvertToUnixTimestamp(DateTime date)
{
    DateTime origin = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    TimeSpan diff = date.ToUniversalTime() - origin;
    return Math.Floor(diff.TotalSeconds);
}

public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
{
    var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
    return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
}
```

Does anyone know what is wrong with the last part's construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is wrong with the last part's construction?

You need to base64UrlEncode the signature hash value

```
public Task<string> GetJWTToken(string user) {

    //...other code removed for brevity

    //constructing part 3: HS512(part1 + "." + part2, key)
    var tobeHashed = string.Join(".", partOne, partTwo);
    var sha = new HMACSHA512(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ConfigurationHelper.AppSettings("JWTOfferKey")));
    var hashedByteArray = sha.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tobeHashed));

    //You need to base64UrlEncode the signature hash value
    var partThree = Base64UrlEncode(hashedByteArray);

    //Now construct the token
    var tokenString = string.Join(".", tobeHashed, partThree);

    //await was not used so no need for `async` keyword. Just return task
    return Task.FromResult(tokenString);
}

// from JWT spec
private static string Base64UrlEncode(byte[] input) {
    var output = Convert.ToBase64String(input);
    output = output.Split('=')[0]; // Remove any trailing '='s
    output = output.Replace('+', '-'); // 62nd char of encoding
    output = output.Replace('/', '_'); // 63rd char of encoding
    return output;
}
```